# UCP algorithm of work

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ucp

I work with Universal connection pool from Oracle. I work on this scheme

```
class Action {
  static PoolDataSource initPool() {
    PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    pds.setURL(".........");
    pds.setUser("user");
    pds.setPassword("pass");
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(0);
    return pds;
  }

  static final PoolDataSource pds = initPool();

  void doAction() {
    Connection connection = pds.getConnection();
    ..........
    connection.close();  // ????
  }
}
```

Do you need to call `connection.close()` after the `doAction` completes or does the whole sense of working with the pool get lost and the connections there should remain open until they themselves close on timeout?

Comment: Yes the close returns it to the connection pool. If you do not, you will leak connections and exhaust the connection pool.

Comment: @KrisRice Thank you. Do you write a comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure I'll put is as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR. YES close them. It doesn't actually close, it returns to the connection pool for the next getConnection() call.

The full doc is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDJCGGB

> Borrowed connections that are no longer being used should be returned
>   to the pool so that they can be available for the next connection
>   request. The close method is used to close connections and
>   automatically returns the connections to the pool. The close method
>   does not physically remove the connection from the pool.
>
> Borrowed connections that are not closed will remain borrowed;
>   subsequent requests for a connection result in a new connection being
>   created if no connections are available. This behavior can cause many
>   connections to be created and can affect system performance.